# When/why can kafka partition unpause "by itself"?

Tags: spring-kafka

I have this kafka consumer:

```
new ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate<>(createReceivingOptions())
```

it happily processes messages, I set

```
max-poll-records=1
```

so that things don't happen to fast for me. I can verify via logging breakpoint in `poll` method on

```
final Map<TopicPartition, List<ConsumerRecord<K, V>>> records = pollForFetches(timer);
```

how many records poll returned, and yes it's one. Then I asked it to pause all assigned partitions. In log is can see that it worked!

```
o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=Testing, groupId=Testing] Pausing partitions [TestTopic-0]
```

and from that point on I can see, that poll gets only 0 records and also this log:

```
Skipping fetching records for assigned partition TestTopic-0 because it is paused
```

OK great, it works! But wait, why is my whole topic getting processed then?

Then I found out, that at certain point there is also this log:

```
Consumer clientId=Testing, groupId=Testing] Resuming partitions [TestTopic-0]
```

what? Who is calling that? And then I also found out, that there are multiple requests for pausing all over place, not just the one I actually invoked.

Pausing is somehow used by reactive and cannot be used manually? Or does someone have explanation why `…clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer` does pause/resume topic on it's own all the time, and manual pause because of that gets unpaused?

Comment: I am not very familiar with the reactor-kafka project, but it does look like it's using pause/resume internally in `ConsumerEventLoop.PollEvent.run()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing the `ConsumerEventLoop` code, the reactive client is using `pause/resume` internally, to handle back pressure - when the downstream can't receive any more data he pauses all assigned partitions and unconditionally resumes them when the back pressure is relieved.

It seems to me that it needs to keep track of whether the pause was done because of back-pressure and only resume in that case.

It looks like it used to do that before [this commit](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-kafka/commit/d908b815bf5a8be41b840a272e6766ad8754783d).

Perhaps you could use back pressure instead to force the pause?

Comment: I just needed to pause processing to update the configuration how records will be processed and it seemed to be better way than shutting down and restarting. But I can (theoretically) shutdown and restart, that's not a problem. However shutting down and comitting last record seems to be way harder than I ever imagined: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66401737/how-to-gracefully-shut-down-reactive-kafka-consumer-and-commit-last-processed-re  But that's different story. Thans for your helpful answer (as always)!