# How to gracefully shut down reactive kafka-consumer and commit last processed record?

Tags: spring-kafka

My painful hunt for this feature is fully described in disgustingly log question: [Several last offsets aren't getting commited with reactive kafka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66398421/several-last-offsets-arent-getting-commited-with-reactive-kafka) and it shows my multiple attemps with different failures.

How would one subscribe to `ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate<String, String>`, which will process the records in synchronous way (for simplicity), and will ack/commit every 2s AND upon manual cancellation of stream? Ie. it works, ack/commits every 2s. Then via rest/jmx/whatever comes signal, the stream terminates and ack/commits the last processed kafka record.

Answer (score 1):

After *a lot* of attempts I was able to come up with following solution. It seems to work, but it's kinda ugly, because it's very "white-box" where outer flow highly depends on stuff happening inside of other methods. **Please criticise and suggest improvements. Thanks.**

```
kafkaReceiver.receive()
    .flatMapSequential(receivedKafkaRecord -> processKafkaRecord(receivedKafkaRecord), 16)
    .takeWhile(e-> !stopped)
    .sample(configuration.getKafkaConfiguration().getCommitInterval())
    .concatMap(offset -> {
        log.debug("ack/commit offset {}", offset.offset());
        offset.acknowledge();
        return offset.commit();
    })
    .doOnTerminate(()-> log.info("stopped."));
```

What didn't work:

A) you cannot use Disposable.dispose, since that would break the stream and your latest processed record won't be committed.

B) you cannot put take on top of stream, as that would cancel the stream and you won't be able to commit either.

C) not sure how I'd be able to intercorporate usage of errors here.

Because of *what didn't work* stream termination is triggered by boolean field named `stopped`, which can be set anyhow.

Flow explained:

1. flatMapSequential — because of inner parallelism and necessity to commit N only if all N-1 was processed.
2. processKafkaRecord returns `Mono<ReceiverOffset>`, ie. the offset of processed record to have something to ack/commit. When `stopped` the method will skip processing and return Mono.empty
3. `take` will stop stream if stopped, this has to be put here becaue of possibility of whole `sample` interval consisting only from "empties"
4. rest is simple: sample by given interval, commit in order. If sample does return empty record, commit is skipped. Finally we log that stream is cancelled.

If anyone know how to improve, please criticise.